# "argument types do not match"

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Any idea whats causing this?
It gives me a runtime

> Arguments type do not match after grouping

although i never assign a non nullable value to a nullable field.

There is literally nothing readable about this error.
All the other posts I've found about this have some sort of nullable field.

```
IList<ProgrammazioneEseguite> parzialiGruppate = 
    (from pe in _db.ProgrammazioneEseguite.AsNoTracking()
        orderby pe.DataOraInizioLavorazione
        group pe by new { pe.Azienda, pe.ComNumero, 
        pe.ComParte, pe.ComPosizione, pe.FaseCiclo }
        into peG
        where peG.Sum(x => x.QtaLavorata) > 0
        select new ProgrammazioneEseguite
        {
            Id = (int)peG.First().Id,
            Azienda = peG.Key.Azienda,
            ComNumero = peG.Key.ComNumero,
            ComParte = peG.Key.ComParte,
            ComPosizione = peG.Key.ComPosizione,
            FaseCiclo = peG.Key.FaseCiclo,
            CodDisegno = null,
            CodSubDisegno = null,
            RevSubDisegno = null,
            FaseCicloSub = null,
            HimpiegateCad = 
            peG.Sum(x => Util.callcolaHimpiegateCad(x.DataOraEsecuzione, x.DataOraInizioLavorazione, x.QtaLavorata) * x.QtaLavorata) / ((double)peG.Sum(x => x.QtaLavorata)), //media pesata per pezzi 
            HimpiegateCadTesto = null,
            HimpiegateTot = null,
            HimpiegateTotTesto = null,
            FlagEseguita = 
            peG.First().FlagEseguita,  //le setto tutte insieme a 1 quando son tutte chiuse
            Operatore = null,
            MacchinaUsata = peG.Last().MacchinaUsata,
            DataFineLavEsterna = peG.First().DataFineLavEsterna,
            DataEsecuzione = null,
            DataOraEsecuzione = null,
            QtaLavorata = peG.Sum(x => x.QtaLavorata),
            DataOraInizioLavorazione = peG.Last().DataOraInizioLavorazione,
            FlagIniziata = (byte)peG.Where(x => x.FlagIniziata > 0).FirstOrDefault().FlagIniziata,
            ProgrDataOraForzata = null,   
            AnnotazioniOperatore = null,
            ColataUtilizzata = null,
            OperatoreFineFase = null,
            FlagAttrezzaggio = null
        }
    ).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

and here's the model

```
public partial class ProgrammazioneEseguite
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Azienda { get; set; }
        public int? ComNumero { get; set; }
        public string ComParte { get; set; }
        public string ComPosizione { get; set; }
        public double FaseCiclo { get; set; }
        public int? CodDisegno { get; set; }
        public int? CodSubDisegno { get; set; }
        public string RevSubDisegno { get; set; }
        public double? FaseCicloSub { get; set; }
        public double? HimpiegateCad { get; set; }
        public string HimpiegateCadTesto { get; set; }
        public double? HimpiegateTot { get; set; }
        public string HimpiegateTotTesto { get; set; }
        public byte? FlagEseguita { get; set; }
        public string Operatore { get; set; }
        public string MacchinaUsata { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataFineLavEsterna { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataEsecuzione { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataOraEsecuzione { get; set; }
        public int? QtaLavorata { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataOraInizioLavorazione { get; set; }
        public byte? FlagIniziata { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProgrDataOraForzata { get; set; }
        public string AnnotazioniOperatore { get; set; }
        public string ColataUtilizzata { get; set; }
        public string OperatoreFineFase { get; set; }
        public byte? FlagAttrezzaggio { get; set; }
    }
```

All the query results are assigned to nullable fields, i'm confused.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy not my fault, its office convention. also i dont think this case matters, its just a query with some field whose type u can see from the model

Comment: `FlagIniziata = (byte)peG.Where(x...).FirstOrDefault().FlagIniziata` should be `FlagIniziata = peG.Where(x...).FirstOrDefault()?.FlagIniziata`, right?

Comment: Please post a full exception message with stack trace.

Comment: Code section indentation fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have something to do with you stating that some of the items should be of a nullable type, try this:

`FlagIniziata = (byte)peG...` should be changed to `FlagIniziata = (byte?)peG...`

and

`((double)peG.Sum(x => x.QtaLavorata)), //media pesata...` should be `((double?)peG.Sum(x => x.QtaLavorata)), //media pesata`